# How can set background image each row GridView

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using Gridview to display items with crossAxisCount , how can I set background image each row﻿
I want to make like this

[image]

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two moderately simple ways of doing this, but I'll have to leave it up to you to implement for now.

This sort of depends on how many books you want to show, and whether you know exactly how many you want to show per shelf.

If you decide you want a constant number of items per row (say 5 books), I believe the simplest solution is to use a ListView, with each item in the ListView a DecoratedBox (or container). This item will have an image background which is the shelf, and a row containing the 5 books.

This should be fairly efficient for a large number of books, as it should only construct each row at a time. The downside is that you need to decide the number of books per row, and will probably have to have separate code to draw when in landscape or narrow aspect ratios (or at least to choose how many books per row, and only if you need landscape). (note that you can get the screen width and could make a decision for how many books per row based on that).

The other way of doing it would be to use a Scrollable, a Stack, and a [Wrap](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html). You'd put the Stack in the Scrollable, and the stack would have two layers - the background, and the items. The background would have to know how to draw based on its height - you may be able to use a BoxDecoration with a DecorationImage and repeat. The Wrap would contain all of the images.

There's a couple things I'm not 100% sure about, like whether the stack would handle resizing to a wrap or not. But I think that would work. The pro would be that it would handle screen rotation & different aspect ratios just fine, but the con would be that it won't handle large amounts of books very well.

There is a third option, but it gets much more complicated (although it's objectively the best way of doing this) - use a CustomScrollView and/or Slivers. I'm not even entirely sure how I'd go about this though, but [these](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) are the docs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I'll try these solution.